# Remove button faces

Tags: rebol, red

**Hi all.**

*I want to know that how can I remove two button face with a button.*

*I tried this:*

```
gui: [
  en: button "English" remove [en es]
  es: button "Spanih" remove [en es]
]
```

*And than I have to append new buttons.*

Comment: 1) You have to use `view` function to display a gui.

2) Button actions have to be enclosed in a block.

Comment: Hi Civan, rather than editing the title of your question to say that it is solved, typically you should mark the best answer as "answered" (the green checkmark). You can also say thanks by upvoting any answers that you found helpful.

Comment: Okay, I got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Red [Needs: View]
view [
    en: button "English" [remove find face/parent/pane en]
    es: button "Spanish" [
        remove find face/parent/pane en
        remove find face/parent/pane es
    ]
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your very quick answer. This code is so good. Well, it is not run with Rebol but it run with Red.

Comment: Hi @CivanTunç, welcome to StackOverflow! If you are satisfied with Maciek's answer, please mark is as an accepted one.

Answer (score 4):

[View engine](https://doc.red-lang.org/en/view.html) models GUI interface as a tree of objects; each node in that tree is called a face, and each field of that face is called a facet.

Two facets, `parent` and `pane`, interlink a face with its parent node and its child nodes, respectively. So, by that theory, to remove a button is to remove a `button` face from a pane of its parent:

```
view [button "Poof!" [probe select take face/parent/pane 'text]]
```

This, however, is a bit limited approach. The removed face is detached from View tree and can no longer be used unless you reattach the `face!` object with the same specification back to the pane. It might be more useful to simply disable a button, or to render it invisible for the time being. `enabled?` and `visible?` facets can achieve just that:

```
view [
    title "Face flags example"
    below
    toggle "Toggle" [foo/enabled?: not foo/enabled?]
    foo: button "Switch" disabled [bar/visible?: not bar/visible?]
    bar: base red
]
```

You can adapt this approach to the task at hand. As I understand, you want to offer mutually exclusive localization options; [`drop-list`](https://doc.red-lang.org/en/view.html#_drop_list) might be a good fit for that:

```
view [drop-list data ["en" "es"]]
```

Comment: Wow! A very explanatory answer. Thank you.